# Get the value of selected option in select2 and then set the value to an input text using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I'm new to jquery and javascript, so maybe this is a silly question but i'm having problems setting the value obtained from a selected option in select2 to a text input. This is my code:

```
  <head>

    <!-- stylesheets -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css">


    <!-- scripts -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>

    <script>
      $(function(){
        // turn the element to select2 select style
        $('.select2').select2({
          placeholder: "Select a state"
        });

        var data = $(".select2 option:selected").text();
        $("#test").val(data);
      });



    </script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <p>select2 select box:</p>
    <p>
      <select  class="select2" style="width:300px">
          <option> </option>
          <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
          <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
          <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
          <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
      </select>
    </p>

    <input type="text" id="test"> 

  </body>

  </html>
```

Any ideas of what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try `var data = $(".select2").val()`

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You are almost there. Put your value assignments within the `change` handler of the dropdown. The way you have it, it's just getting called when the page is loaded.

```
  $(function(){
    // turn the element to select2 select style
    $('.select2').select2({
      placeholder: "Select a state"
    });

    $('.select2').on('change', function() {
      var data = $(".select2 option:selected").text();
      $("#test").val(data);
    })
  });
```

Comment: What about initial selection? On change/select2:select events are not firing on it. initSelection was deprecated and now referenced to some data adapter...

Comment: How to get the id?

Answer (score 20):

As per the docs https://select2.org/programmatic-control/events#event-data

```
$('.select2').on('select2:select', function (e) {
    var data = e.params.data;
    $('#test').val(data.text);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [change event](https://select2.github.io/options.html#events): whenever an option is selected the value can be copied to the text box:

```js
$(function(){
  // turn the element to select2 select style
  $('.select2').select2({
    placeholder: "Select a state"
  }).on('change', function(e) {
    var data = $(".select2 option:selected").text();
    $("#test").val(data);
  });

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<p>select2 select box:</p>
<p>
    <select  class="select2" style="width:300px">
        <option> </option>
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
        <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
        <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
    </select>
</p>

<input type="text" id="test">
```

Comment: Thank you for the alternative solution!

Answer (score 2):

simply you can do this:

```
$('#your-select-id').on("change", function(e) {
                console.log($("#your-select-id").val())
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#e15").on("change", function () {
    $("#e15_val").html($("#e15").val());
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

I am adding this here because, a couple of months back, the answers provided here worked for me, but now, some voodoo happened and the only way for me to get the value of a selected item was doing the following:

```
$('.findUser').select2({
    minimumInputLength: 3,
    placeholder: "Search Members...",
    allowClear: true,
    dropdownAutoWidth : true,
    width: '250px'
}).on('change', function (e) {
    console.log(e.val);
});
```

As you can see, I used `e.val` to get the value. The only way I could get the trigger of the selected value to work was using `change` since using `select2:select` simply would not work (Which it did a couple of months back if I reckon). To debug and get to this point I had to do a `console.log(e)` to get all events when it triggered the on change case. I also saw that you could use `e.added.text` to get the text of the option and `e.added.id` to get the id, which is similar to `e.val` mentioned previously.

In case you need to test e.vale agains a condition, make sure to turn it into a string or numeric. Like this:

`var newValue = (e.val).toString();`

This way we can make sure that, if the value is empty (false) it will return false properly in a condition and if it has any value in it, it will return true as it should. The reason is that if I leave it as an object, it will always be true. Also this method works flawlessly with multiple selected options, just by adding the parameter `multiple="multiple"` to the select tag.

This was tested (Surprisingly) with Select2 4.0.8, Select2 3.5.2 and Select2 3.5.3 and it ended up working. Again I am pretty sure the other answers here worked, but now I had to resort to this trickery to get it to work (After 2 hours figuring out why it did not).

Answer (score -2):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Init select2
    $('#id').select2();
    // Log selected value to console
    $('#id').on('change', function(e) {
        console.log($('#id').select2("val")); 
    });
});
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.